# Eclipse JAD result

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, decompiler

I have a very basic question. When I decompile any java class using JAD in eclipse I can find that it there are comment lines like. What does this mean? and how to reference one class in another in eclipse.

```
//Referenced classes of package <package name>:
//     DetailedLoginException
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it lists the classes of the package `<package name>` which are being referenced/used by this class(decompiled class). And the `<package name>` is also same as the decompiled class's package. Like in following example `Assert` and `ComparisonFailure` both belongs to `org.junit` package.

```
package org.junit;

import org.hamcrest.*;
.....

// Referenced classes of package org.junit:
//            ComparisonFailure

public class Assert
{
```